# XMLhttpRequest with a node js server with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

for a reason that i don't know i can't use the xmlhttprequest in my local server created in node js and express. Let me show you...
Here is the server in node JS:

```
var 
express = require('express'),
app = express.createServer();

app.get('/count', function(req, res) {
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.write('Hello!')
     res.end();
});

app.listen(4003);
```

And it runs jus fine! when i acess localhost:4003/count i see "Hello!".

Now that the server is O.K, let's check the html page:

```
<script>

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var resp = ""
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        resp = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
}

var cam = "localhost:4003/count"


function show(){
    xmlhttp.open("GET",cam,  true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    alert(resp);
}

</script>

<center><h1><div style="color:#339966"> <input type="button" value="Return of /count" onclick="javascript:show()"> </div> </h1>
```

So, it just don't work =[, i've already tried to:

- change `localhost:4003/count` as value of the variable `cam`, for `http://localhost:4003/count`, `127.0.0.1:4003/count`.
- Open in Firefox, Safari and Chrome.
- When i try to see the `xmlhttp.status` with an `alert()` it shows '`0`'. (but the page open normally in any browser)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Along with the timing issues that [Morgan already covered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18414060/15031)...

- When including a host in a URL, it needs to be prefixed by `//`.

  ```
  var cam = "//localhost:4003/count";
  ```

  Otherwise, it'll be treated as a relative path with `localhost:4003` as a directory name.
- You also have to deal with the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) when using Ajax.

  So, if you're trying to use `file://` for the page, this won't typically work well. The `FILE` protocol doesn't have an origin, so it can't pass the SOP, resulting in errors similar to:

  ```
  Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
  ```

  The easiest solution is to also serve the page from the application.

  You can do so either with a [`static()` middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html).

  ```
  // `GET /` will serve `./public/index.html`
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  ```

  Or with another route that [sends the file](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendfile) itself.

  ```
  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
  });
  ```

  Then, access the page from:

  ```
  http://localhost:4003/
  ```
- Also, with both the page and the `count` now served from the same origin, the URL can simply be relative-from-root:

  ```
  var cam = "/count";
  ```

Comment: IT WORKET! i can't thank you guys enough, really really thanks! you deserve everything good of this world! You guys are angels! Really thanks!

Answer (score 2):

At the time you are trying to `alert(resp)` the `resp` variable hasn't been assigned, because `onreadystatechange` has not been called. If you moved the alert into `onreadystatechange` you should get the desired effect. This is also the point you could assign that value to an `Element` in the page.

Comment: I tried it, and guess what, the code in the if isn't reached, think that's because the xmlhttp.status is not 200, i tested and it is 0. =[

Comment: @user2694468 How are you requesting the page that's making the request? If you're using `file://`, that doesn't typically support making Ajax requests. If you're instead using `http://`, is it served from the [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) -- `http://localhost:4003/page.html`?

Comment: That is right, you need to serve the html from Express also (instead of using file:///). You can look at the static middleware to see how this is done.

Comment: Actually, the nodeJS (with express) server "writes" in the page for me, when i do app.get(/something,... in my localhost:port/something will execute the code block above the app.get, i this case i orederd the server to write "hello" in the page. I just want to het the "hello" text in the page created by the nodeJS server =[

Comment: The main question here is how are you serving the HTML in your example?

Comment: the Problem is that the xmlhttp.status is = 0.

Comment: @user2694468 That's the symptom, not the cause. There's a reason why it's remaining `0` and that's what we're trying to figure that out.

Comment: No, actually i just want to get the value from localhost:4003/count direct from the html page.
The page localhost:4003/count hast just a text write a numer, for example: 0

Comment: @user2694468 Ajax isn't all-allowing. There are security restrictions you need to stay within. If you don't, the request will be forced to abort, resulting in `status === 0`. See my answer for more details.